# How to exclude files for pushing

Tags: git, version-control

I have remote server with a git and local development machine. I need to don't send some files from my working directory on a server but stay it on version control of my local git. Let's say I have the following files on my local dev machine.

```
assets
   |-css
   |-js
compiles
   -css
   -js
index.html
```

All files are on version control, but when I need to make push I don't want it for 'assets' folder. How can I do that?

**EDIT:**
Let me explain the situation. I'm a single developer and I do concatenate and  minimize of my aseets files into compiled folder. So I don't need to push assets folder because production code uses compiles.

Answer (score 7):

I have found 2 answers to this:

1. For a few files:
   `git update-index --assume-unchanged FILE`
2. For many files/directories, or more permanent for that environment, or to share file list across environments:

   - Instead of using .gitignore, which will remove it from all version control, the file or folder can be added to : `.git/info/exclude`.
   - If one wanted to pull all of the repo from the repo to local or to another server (like staging), then another local clone can be made but without the local `/exclude` so it will grab everything.

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer is **No, you cannot have different set of files on a given branch when you push a repo from local to remote**.

Like others mentioned, you should be able to use `.gitignore` to exclude the `assets` directory totally from version control (on both local and remote repos):

```
# Your repo's .gitignore
/assets/*
```

Answer (score 3):

You can edit `.gitignore`. if you want to only works in local. You can edit `.git/info/exclude` like this

.git/info/exclude

```
# git ls-files --others --exclude-from=.git/info/exclude
# Lines that start with '#' are comments.
# For a project mostly in C, the following would be a good set of
# exclude patterns (uncomment them if you want to use them):
# *.[oa]
# *~
./assets/*
```

OR

.gitignore

```
./assets/*
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .gitignore to select what you don't want to push it up to git server.

Just put `.gitignore` to your root folder and add `./assets/*` to this file.

You may look https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files for more information

Comment: If I do that I remove all files from assets from version control

Comment: Yes, you are right. add .gitignore and remove it can't not keep two different versions on server and client at the same time....

Answer (score -1):

In my Opinion,this case can be divided into two git projects:
1.assets
2.others